# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un actualizar automáticamente con Ajax y Php?

Tags: php, ajax

Necesito actualizar el total de un producto automáticamente cuando haya puesto su cantidad en un campo numérico, cada vez que ponga una cantidad diferente debe mostrarse su total, agradecería si alguien sabe dónde lo puedo ver, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto pero con .post de jquery, que es muy similar a ajax. 
Vamos a suponer que tenemos que actualizar la edad de un usuario. En la función que he creado estoy pasando 2 valores; El primero, el nombre del div y el segundo es el nombre del campo en la base de datos. Lo hice de esta forma para que sea mas fácil editar otros campos luego, y quise añadir el campo de la base de datos ya que en ciertas ocasiones podemos usar el id con un nombre distinto al del campo en la bd.
Es importante decir, que solamente se actualizara, cuando el usuario saque el foco del input, si quieres que sea apenas presione una tecla, en input en vez de usar onchange, podrías usar onkeyup, pero es importante validar también, que no quede vació el campo o sea igual a 0. Eso ya lo puedes agregar mas adelante, con php o jquery.
He agregado un div con el id alert, para actualizar luego con los resultados.

Archivo html (IMPORTANTE AÑADIR LIBRERIA JQUERY):

```
<input type="text" id="edad" onchange="actualizar('edad','edad_usuario')">
<div id="alert"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function actualizar(div, campo_bd){
        var value = $('#'+div).val();
        var jqxhr = $.post( "actualizar.php", { 'campo_bd' : campo_bd, 'value' : value  } );
        jqxhr.done(function( data ) {
          $("#alert").html(data);
        });

      }
</script>
```

Archivo PHP:

```
<?php 
$campo = $_POST['campo_bd'];
$valor = $_POST['value'];
$q = "UPDATE usuario SET ".$campo." = '".$valor."' WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario'";
$mysqli->query($q);
echo 'datos actualizados';
?>
```

Saludos.